# Project euler # 25 code heap space error

Tags: java

I am trying to complete problem 25 on the project euler website but I am getting the Java heap space error. How do i go about solving this?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Problem25 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int a = 1;
        int b = 1;
        int c;
        ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        nums.add(1);
        nums.add(1);
        for(int i = 2; ;i++){
            c = a+b;
            nums.add(c);
            if(nums.get(i).toString().length() == 1000)
                System.out.print(nums.get(i));
            a++;
            b++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Under what conditions do you think your for-loop will terminate?

Comment: Seems like your `for-loop` never stop. You need a condition.. `for(int i=2; condition; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 2; ;i++){
```

You missed a condition when the loop will break.All you are doing is adding Integers and the loop continues forever.In some time,`ArrayList` becomes too large and throws a Java Heap space error

Answer (score 0):

This program is very far away from solving [Euler #25](https://projecteuler.net/problem=25):

- The loop is not calculating the Fibonacci sequence
- The loop will never exit: loop condition missing in `for(int i = 2; ;i++)` and there's nothing in the loop body to exit the loop
- The length of numbers in `ArrayList<Integer>` will never reach 1000: the largest possible `Integer` is 2147483647, and its length is 10

  - As a side note, a `List` is unnecessary to solve this problem
  - In the posted code you could replace `nums.get(i)` with `Integer.toString(c)` and delete ALL statements involving `nums` to get the same result. (None of this matters though, because of the first point above)

Some tips to solve this:

- Use `BigInteger` to generate the Fibonacci sequence

  - It's easy to find example implementations using `int`. Replace `int` with `BigInteger`
- Use a simple `int` counter to find the index